# Iconv return incorrect string in phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony4, iconv

I have project in SF4 and use phpunit 6.5.8. I tested service that use iconv:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string)
```

When I use this service in application and when $string has value: "ąbć", returned is "abc" but when the same service is runed in phpunit returned is "?b?".

I don't understand why it don't work... Of course the test is negative but in application it works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved a problem. Php in CLI don't set locale. So we must set it before tests.

## 1. Check location which you have in system:

```
locale -a
```

For example:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
```

## 2. In the tests add:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.utf8');
```

## 3. Example:

```
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.utf8');
    }
```

source:

- http://php.net/manual/pl/function.iconv.php#86077
- http://php.net/manual/pl/function.iconv.php#77315

Answer (score 0):

I made one Class to work with strings and one of methods use iconv.

When using phpunit in Windows, iconv fails to transliterate for locale issues. 
Even using setlocale() on the code, the results is always a test fail using code below

```
/**
 * @param $str Convert string to lowercase and replace special chars to equivalents ou remove its
 * @return string
 */
public static function slugify($str)
{
    $str = self::toUtf8($str); // Convert from any encoding to UTF-8
    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str); // transliterate
    $str = strtolower($str); // lowercase
    return $str;
}
```

Unit Test

```
public function testSlugfy()
{
    // Basic String
    $str = StringUtils::slugify($this->basicstring);
    $this->assertEquals(strtolower($this->basicstring), $str, 'Basic String cannot be slugfied');

    // Latin String
    $str = StringUtils::slugify($this->latinstring);
    $this->assertEquals(strtolower($this->basicstring), $str, 'Latin1 String cannot be slugfied');

    // UTF-8 String
    $str = StringUtils::slugify($str);
    $this->assertEquals(strtolower($this->basicstring), $str, 'UTF8 String cannot be slugfied');

}
```

Don't have any troubles in my App but the PHPUnit Test fails with code above.

So, to pass the test i change the function to

```
/**
 * @param $str Convert string to lowercase and replace special chars to equivalents ou remove its
 * @return string
 */
public static function slugify($str)
{
    $string = self::toUtf8($str);
    $string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);

    if ($string != htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) { // iconv fails
        $string = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $string = preg_replace('#&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);#i', '$1', $string);
// If need to leave only 0-9, a-z and A-Z
//            $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
//            $string = preg_replace(array('#[^0-9a-z]#i', '#[ -]+#'), ' ', $string);
        $string = trim($string, ' -');
    }

    // lowercase
    $str = strtolower($string);

    return $str;
}
```

And on the Unit Test class constructor I create strings with another approach, to avoid troubles with file charset and locale issues.

```
private $basicstring;
private $latinstring;
private $utf8string;

public function __construct()
{
    // ASCII string
    $this->basicstring = 'aeioucAEIOUC';

    // To avoid troubles using command line in different locales
    // the string used to create different charset is a plain HTML entities
    // Using html_entity_decode to convert the
    // string &atilde;&eacute;&igrave;&ocirc;&uuml;&ccedil;&Atilde;&Eacute;&igrave;&Ocirc;&Uuml;&Ccedil;
    // into ãéìôüçÃÉìÔÜÇ in different charsets
    $html_chars = '&atilde;&eacute;&igrave;&ocirc;&uuml;&ccedil;&Atilde;&Eacute;&igrave;&Ocirc;&Uuml;&Ccedil;';
    $this->utf8string = html_entity_decode($html_chars, ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
    $this->latinstring = html_entity_decode($html_chars, ENT_HTML5, 'ISO-8859-1');
    parent::__construct();
}
```

I'm also using Symfony 4